# GDALOpenEx define papszOpenOptions

Tags: gdal, ogr, c++

I'm using GDAL/OGR to open shapefiles. Now i'm calling this method to open a dataset:

```
dataset = (GDALDataset *)GDALOpenEx(path.toStdString().c_str(), GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL,NULL, NULL);
```

I read in http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a9cb8585d0b3c16726b08e25bcc94274a that i can define option with NULL, or a NULL terminated list of strings the dataset open options using the papszOpenOptions var.

I don't undestand with the documentation how is this `cons char* const*`

must be declared.

Could some one help me?

I want set the Overview level in the open method.

Comment: You are using shapefiles but overview levels belong to raster datasets. Question about how to use open options is relevant but overviews in context of vector data are not.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the information. I Supose that would be worked whith shape files too. Do you know how can i simplify a shapefile in the opening call?

Comment: Use ExecuteSQL with SQLite SQL dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html. Then you can utilize the SpatiaLite function ST_Simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me the easiest way is using **CSLAddNameValue**

```
char **papszOptions = nullptr;
papszOptions = CSLAddNameValue(papszOptions, "KEY", "VALUE");
```

Don't forget to free options list after using:

```
CSLDestroy( papszOptions );
```

Also see [GDAL Documentation](http://www.gdal.org/cpl__string_8h.html#a140315b0903d52c438c143894f0d9847)